# Search for specific line followed by specific line ( TXT file ) in python

Tags: python, file, search, text, line

i want to print interfaces that don't have qos under it ,,
i have txt file like below

```
interface 1
 qos
 trust
interface 2
 trust
interface 3
 trust
 qos
interface 4
 trust 
 trust
 qos
interface 5
 trust
interface 6
```

i want the output to be as below  (output wanted):

```
interface 2
interface 5
interface 6
```

any help plz ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When you post questions, provide us with what you have done. We cannot write the full code for you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes the problem challenging is that you need to gather all of the information before you can find some results.

#### Code

```
def no_qos(lines):
    # keep track of interfaces seen and which has qos
    interfaces = []
    has_qos = set()

    # scan the file and gather interfaces and which have qos
    for line in lines:
        if not line.startswith(' '):
            interface = line.strip()
            interfaces.append(interface)
        elif line.startswith(" qos"):
            has_qos.add(interface)

    # report which interfaces do not have qos
    return [i for i in interfaces if i not in has_qos]
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = '''
interface 1
 qos
 trust
interface 2
 trust
interface 3
 trust
 qos
interface 4
 trust
 trust
 qos
interface 5
 trust
interface 6
'''

for interface in no_qos(data.split('\n')):
    print(interface)
```

#### Results:

```
interface 2
interface 5
interface 6
```

Comment: yea , its worked for me thanks alot , but excuse me im new in python , how to read data from file and do the same code on it .

Comment: The original code you edited out of your questions shows how to read the file.